# ¿como llamo al metodo para guardar los datos en el array dentro del jframe?

Tags: java, jframe

Buenas tengo un formulario con una serie de cosas, entonces la idea es que los datos que he dado se guarden en un array. Tengo una clase persona una clase Formulario y le Jframe. Mi problema es que no se como llamar al metodo añadir formulario para meter los datos de la persona que he creado en el formulario.
Esta es mi clase formulario

```
package Clases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author ck
 */
public class Formulario {

    private List<Persona> formulario;

    public Formulario(List<Persona> formulario) {
        this.formulario = formulario;
    }

    public Formulario() {
        this.formulario = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Persona> getFormulario() {
        return formulario;
    }

    public void setFormulario(List<Persona> formulario) {
        this.formulario = formulario;
    }

    public void aniadirPersona(Persona P) {
        formulario.add(P);

    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que trae mi boton guardar que en teoria solo le falta el metodo añadirpersona

```
private void botonGuardarContactoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        Archivo archivo = new Archivo();

        archivo.crearArchivo();

        String usuario,password,edad,telefono;
        // Obtenemos los datos de las cajas de texto
        usuario = cajaUsuario.getText();
        password = cajaPassword.getText();
        edad = cajaEdad.getText();
        telefono = cajaTelefono.getText();

        //creamos un objeto persona

        Persona persona = new Persona (usuario, password, edad, telefono);

        //Escribimos los datos de la persona enel archivo

        archivo.escibirTexto(persona);
        //vaciamos el contenido de las cajas
        cajaUsuario.setText("");
        cajaPassword.setText("");
        cajaEdad.setText("");
        cajaTelefono.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de crear la persona, creas un formulario y le agregas la persona

```
Persona persona = new Persona (usuario, password, edad, telefono);
Formulario formulario = new Formulario();
formulario.aniadirPersona(persona);
```

pero tené en cuenta que se va a crear un objeto Formulario cada vez que se presione el botón guardarContacto, para evitar esto hay que declarar estático al menos el método **aniadirPersona**, `public static void aniadirPersona(Persona P)`, entonces creas el objeto Formulario, dentro de algún constructor, por única vez, luego para llamar al método: `Formulario.aniadirPersona(persona)`. Pero deberías mostrar la estructura de clases, o sea donde se encuentra la clase Formulario, el Jframe, minimamente